# Regex to match url()'s in inline styles <div style="url()">

Tags: javascript, regex

[Yes, I know, I know.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Should work everywhere :)

But especially those I find tricky:

```
<div style="background-image:url('img.png');"></div>
<div style='background-image:url("img.png");'></div>
<div style='background-image:url(img.png);'></div>
<div style='background-image:url(../../img.png);'></div>
<div style='background:  #ffffff   url( "img.png" )   no-repeat right top;'></div>
```

Note: should work in JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want anything inside every `url(`...`)`

```
url\(\s*(['"]?)(.*?)\1\s*\)

url    # literal characters 
\(     # escaped left parenthesis to treat it as literal
\s*    # 0 or more white-space characters
(      # 1st capture group
 ['"]? # either ' or " or neither
)      # end 1st capture group
(.*?)  # 2nd (main) capture group, any characters, reluctantly
\1     # back-reference group #1, to ensure that same quote type is used at end
\s*    # 0 or more white-space characters
\)     # escaped right parenthesis to treat it as literal
```

http://rubular.com/r/P6FJwxC0L7

If you want only .png files inside every `url(`...`.png)`

```
url\(\s*(['"]?)(.*?\.png)\1\s*\)
```

EDIT: allowance for spaces, and removed useless back-reference

Comment: Thanks! Can you check the fifth example, with the additional spaces?

Comment: Edited to handle your 5th test

Answer (score 0):

I think you should get the inner text of the `style` attribute somehow, and then use the following regex:

```
background-image:(?: )*url\((?:'|")?([^'"]*)(?:'|")?\);
```

The only matched group will be the contents of background-image's url, without optional leading and/or trailing quotes (either `"` or `'`)

Answer (score 0):

This should work `\\(['"]?([\w./]+)`

Answer (score 0):

Another way to go would be to anchor the start of the match after `url(` and possible spaces or quote, `\burl\( *['"]?` and match everything that follows until you find a space, quote, or closed parenthesis `([^'" )]+)`.

```
var txt='url("/webworks/art/yankee/yankee2.gif")';
var url=(/\burl\( *['"]?([^'" )]+)/.exec(txt)||[])[1];

url>>
/webworks/art/yankee/yankee2.gif
```

written with  `|| []`` at the end allows a non-match to return undefined rather than throwing an error.

Answer (score 0):

I'd match urls by a simple pattern first `/url\([^(]+\)/ig`, and then remove all the unnecessary symbols from the result:

```
var matches = html.match(/url\([^(]+\)/ig);
for(var i = 0; i < matches.length; i++)
    // this is a clean url
    var url = matches[i].replace(/(^url\s*\(\s*['"]?)|(['"]?\s*\)$)/ig, '');
```

You could find the full code snippet on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FSjNj/).